# SQL Server CE records gone when app is forced close or restarted device while app is open

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sql-server-ce

I have this odd problem with my records using SQL Server CE in my WPF application. So far I have been successful in storing records on my database. I have a set of settings that I access when opening the application. I'm using LINQPad in order to view my database records.

Here's how I save my database records.

```
using (var dbc = new MyDbContext())
{
    var settings = new UserSetting();
    settings.UserId = AppUser.User.Id;
    settings.MinimizeKey = minimizeKey;
    settings.StartStopKey = startStopKey;
    settings.IsStartAtStartUp = isStartAtStartUp ?? false;
    settings.IsStoreState = isStoreState ?? false;
    dbc.UserSettings.Add(settings);
    dbc.SaveChanges();
}
```

After saving, I view my settings table and I can see that the records are there. My problem is, when I restart my device while the application is currently open. The record seems to be gone. On the other hand, when I close my application before restarting, the records are still there. Obviously restarting the device while the app is still open is not a good practice, but this will happen once in a while and I want my records to still be there.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, sql ce has a flush interval of 10 seconds. You can set it to 1 second by adding:

```
;Flush interval=1
```

To your connection string

Or you can force immediate flush, as described here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/05/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-of-week_21.html

Comment: From what I understand flush means to delete everything right? Why will I set it to 1? I want my data to stay, not to be flushed. Or am I not getting it?

Comment: I tried your answer and here's my connection string "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\EmberDatabase.sdf;password=password;Flush interval=1" Still experiencing the same problem